# Qt QByteArray issue

Tags: qt

I've tried the following:

```
qDebug() << QByteArray("\x00\x10\x00\x00").size();
```

and i get 0 instead of 4 witch i would espect.

What would be a good data type to hold this 4 bytes of data as i need to later write them to a socket so they must remain exactly like you see them above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor `QByteArray(const char* str)` uses `qstrlen` on the argument. Since your string starts with a 0x00 byte, `qstrlen` returns 0, thus the resulting QByteArray is 0 bytes long.

To avoid the `qstrlen` check, use the `QByteArray(const char* str, int size)` constructor:

```
qDebug() << QByteArray("\x00\x10\x00\x00", 4).size();
```

will print 4 as you expect.